# Amenability as a geometric property

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Let  $G$   be a  discrete, finitely  generated, and amenable group.  Let  $H$  be  a  group  which is quasi- isometric  to  $G$. Is  $H$ amenable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This is essentially an immediate consequence of the [Folner sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B8lner_sequence) definition of amenability. You can find references at Theorem 10.23 of the article by Ghys and de la Harpe, "[Infinite groups as geometric objects](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/infinitegroups.pdf)".